# Xml в Dbf конвертор (Java)

Tags: java, xml, dbf

Нужно написать конвертор xml файлов в dbf (чтобы в конечном файле теги xml отображались как столбцы). В программировании новичок поэтому не могу понять с какой стороны подступиться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать (с использованием Java)
Вот пример xml файла (4 записи Assignee типа):

```
<Packet N="049658" Date="2020-6-8" Author="035678124" SumAll="21368,86" INN="1111111113" KPP="111111114" BIK="111111115"
        BankName="Текст" PlaceBank=""
        AccCount="11111111111111111111" CorrCount="11111111111111111112" BranchBank="" FilBank="" Type="Р" Vip="Н">
    <Assignee ID="0">
        <InfJ>
            <FNameJ>ИВАНОВ</FNameJ>
            <LNameJ>ИВАН</LNameJ>
            <MNameJ>ИВАНОВИЧ</MNameJ>
            <SNILSD>026-558-472 96</SNILSD>
        </InfJ>
        <PersonalData>
            <FName>ПЕТРОВ</FName>
            <LName>ПЕТР</LName>
            <MName>ПЕТРОВИЧ</MName>
            <Dborn>1999-09-19</Dborn>
            <Sex>М</Sex>
            <SNILS>054-416-344 12</SNILS>
            <INN_PP/>
            <Citizen/>
            <Status>1</Status>
            <ForeignAdr/>
        </PersonalData>
        <Address>
            <ZipCode>443000</ZipCode>
            <Region>САМАРСКАЯ ОБЛ</Region>
            <District>КИРОВСКИЙ Р-ОН</District>
            <City>САМАРА Г.</City>
            <Settlement/>
            <Street>ЛЕНИНА УЛ.</Street>
            <House>1</House>
            <Case/>
            <Flat/>
        </Address>
        <IdentityCard>
            <CodDocum>54</CodDocum>
            <Series>11 11</Series>
            <Number>111222</Number>
            <Date>2000-01-01</Date>
            <Org>ОТДЕЛОМ ВНУТРЕННИХ ДЕЛ КИРОВСКОГО РАЙОНА САМАРСКОЙ ОБЛАСТИ</Org>
        </IdentityCard>
        <Payment>
            <Summa>111111</Summa>
            <NumAccRec/>
            <PTAddres>443000,САМАРСКАЯ ОБЛ,КИРОВСКИЙ Р-ОН,САМАРА Г.,,ЛЕНИНА УЛ.,1,,</PTAddres>
            <Source>СТК</Source>
        </Payment>
    </Assignee>
</Packet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как никто не ответил, я разобрался сам. Если у кого-нибудь возникнет подобный вопрос то следует делать так:

1. Читать xml файл с помощью SAX или DOM
2. Записывать dbf файл с помощью сторонней библиотеки (я использую эту: https://github.com/albfernandez/javadbf)